# Adjust width of spacer between Mac OS dock icons

Tags: macos, icons, dock

Many of you might know that it is possible to add a spacer to the Mac OS dock icons with:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '{"tile-type"="spacer-tile";}'
$ killall Dock
```

But I find them a bit wide. How can I adjust the space of those *spacers*?

Here's an image of the spacers I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: You may want to get this migrated over to AskDifferent. They specialize in that type of thing.

Comment: @FlareCat already did, I thought I leave this here too though!

Comment: Oh, alright. From the looks of it, you're giving the command a description of what to add with `'{"tile-type"="spacer-tile";}'`. Perhaps there is another "argument" you can provide to set the size of it?

Comment: @FlareCat yeah that's what I thought too, but all efforts didn't bring a result. It seems like there's nothing for this.

Comment: the dupe of this question lives at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250723/adjust-width-of-spacer-between-mac-os-dock-icons

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `{"tile-type"="small-spacer-tile";}`:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '{"tile-type"="small-spacer-tile";}' && killall Dock
```

> Here, a "small-spacer-tile" vs a "spacer-tile":
>
> [image]

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/273540/37797

Answer (score 1):

Here is my collection hope it helps there is a spacer for each side honestly. its in the apple documentation.

### (1) Left Side Spacer (Main dock area)​

*(Choose which size you want)*

(Big Spacer)

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '{tile-data={}; tile-type="spacer-tile";}'

killall Dock
```

---

(Small Spacer)

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '{tile-data={}; tile-type="small-spacer-tile";}'

killall Dock
```

### (2) Right Side Spacer  (area where folders and trashcan is)​

*(Choose which size you want)*

(Big Spacer)

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-others -array-add '{tile-data={}; tile-type="spacer-tile";}'

killall Dock
```

---

(Small Spacer)

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-others -array-add '{tile-data={}; tile-type="small-spacer-tile";}'

killall Dock
```

### (3) Removing Dock Dividers:​

**By Terminal:**

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock persistent-apps
defaults delete com.apple.dock persistent-others

killall Dock
```

**By Click and Drag**

…. Or by simply dragging it off your dock

---

### (4) Links and Bonus Dock Secrets

**Base Article:**
https://davidwalsh.name/dock-dividers

**More Dock Secrets here:**
https://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/unlock-the-macos-docks-hidden-secrets-in-terminal/